# How to add custom library in android studio java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

I have downloaded a **source** of **library** but I really need to make it **custom** and change it in my own way, so I should import it as a module to my project manually.

Comment: I found your answer, please do it like this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-android-studio/16639227#16639227](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-android-studio/16639227#16639227)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Follow these steps:***
1. Create a folder.
2. Drag or copy your library folder in created library in android studio.
3. Add the module to the settings.gradle like this:
include ':LibraryFolder:LibFolder'.
4. So sync it and clean project.
5. Go to project structure in Android Studio.
6. Add library.
7. Clean and run.

**Be successful.**